# While True: loop hangs after a few seconds

Tags: pyqgis

I am brand new to PyQGIS and am at the very beginning of a project to create a Python script that continuously logs data to a text file using the location from the GPS toolbar to look up the value of an attribute from a vector layer that corresponds to the coordinates of the GPS.  Ultimately the script will log data from the underlying vector layer based on the GPS coordinates as a tractor drives across an agricultural field.  Because I am at the beginning of the project, most of the functionality has not been implemented.  So far I have just tried to create the infinite loop that continuously looks up a value from the attribute table on the vector layer and prints it to the console.  Right now the XY coordinates are static.  What I am working on now is trying to get the loop to keep running until I hit the ESC key.  The loop works for about 5 seconds until QGIS "goes donuts" (i.e., becomes unresponsive while the blue donut circles on the screen).  Also, the ESC functionality to end the loop does not work.  I am cobbling together Python code from different Stack Exchange conversations, so maybe some of what I am doing with the While True: loop is not appropriate for QGIS.

```py
import time
import msvcrt
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('RS18_19-CCS Plot Map 14 plots with Treatments and Rates Joined')[0]
while True:
    MyPnt = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(-77.926819,40.724967))
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    for feat in feats:
        if MyPnt.intersects(feat.geometry()):
            rate = feat['StarterRat']
            print(rate)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if msvcrt.kbhit() and ord(msvcrt.getch()) == 27:
        break
```

Comment: You're creating a blocking loop on the main thread, which is why QGIS hangs. Look at creating a threaded timer that fires every 5 seconds, there's pyqt, python threading and 3rd party library ways to do this.